# React array how can i have access to all positions

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops, jsx

i've just started with coding and right now i'm fighting trying to understand arrays. Now i'm trying to create a table from a multidimensional array:

> ```
>  {
>                       this.state.food.map(function(item, key) {
>                           return (
>                             <Table.Body key={key}>
>                               <Table.Row>
>                                 <Table.Cell>{item}</Table.Cell>
>                               </Table.Row>
>                             </Table.Body>
>                           )
>                       })
>                     }
> ```

this code renders something like "chickenfishpotato"in a single cell.I want them to be separated in several cell, like:

> ```
>      <Table.Cell>{item[0}</Table.Cell>--->chicken 
>      <Table.Cell>{item[1]}</Table.Cell>--->fish
> ```
>
> but dinamically, i don't want to insert the position of each item. I tried to do that but it doesn't work:
>
> ```
> {
>                       this.state.food.map(function(item, key) {
>                           return (
>                             <Table.Body key={key}>
>                             <Table.Row>
>                             {
>                               for(let i = 0; i < item.length; i++){
>                                 return(
>                                 <Table.Cell>{item[i]}</Table.Cell>
>                                 )
>                               }
>                             }
>                               </Table.Row>
>                             </Table.Body>
>                           )
>                       })
>                     }
> ```

i can't understand what's wrong. Could you explain me?

Answer (score 1):

Since for-loops can't be used inside JSX elements, so instead of using `for loop` inside render, you would use `map`. Assuming item is an array, you could loop over it directly,

```
{
                  this.state.food.map(function(item, key) {
                      return (
                        <Table.Body key={key}>
                        <Table.Row>
                        {
                          item.map(data => (
                            <Table.Cell key={data}>{data}</Table.Cell>
                            )
                          }
                          </Table.Row>
                        </Table.Body>
                      )
                  })
                }
```

incase item is an object , you need to loop over its keys like `Object.keys(item).map()` or values like `Object.values(item).map()`

Answer (score 0):

As Shubham Kharti answered, you can use `map` instead.

Better to name this variable as `items` for readability, so it would be

`items.map(item => <Table.Cell key={item}>{item}</Table.Cell>)`

As for your code, you tried to return from `for` statement, but `for` statement doesn't create new functional `scope` for you, that means that when your jsx will be converted into `React.createElement` statements, there will be `for` statement that jsx doesn't know.

On the other hand `Array.prototype.map` will return the new array with the values you return from a passed function (first parameter)

If you would like to use `for`, it's possible, but with something like this

```
var rows = [];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    rows.push(<Table.Cell>{items[i]}</Table.Cell>)
}

return rows
```